# php form with database embed in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating custom form in php and using database. I want to integrate that form in wordpress; for this i create one template(customform.php) and adding in page. My php code is smoothly running on xampp but not in wordpress.

Please help me to integrate code in wordpress.

```
/*CustomForm php*/
<?php /* Template Name: CustomForm */ ?>
<?php  require_once("conn.php");?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<div id="content" class="full-width">
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

<body>
    <form name="course_information" id="course_information" method="post" action="course_information_action.php" >
    <div>
    <h1 class="heading">Product Details</h1>
    <h3>Product Type</h3>
    <?php
        $sql = "select id,course from course_master";   
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        $selectbox = '';

        $selectbox .= '<select id="course_master" name="course_master" class="select_style"><option value="0"> -- select --</option>';
        while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $selectbox .= "<option value=".$data['id'].">".$data['course']."</option>";
        }
        $selectbox .= '</select>';
        echo $selectbox;
    ?>

    <h3>Product</h3>

    <div><select class="select_style" id="course_details" name="course_details" >
        <option value="0"> -- select --</option>
    </select></div>


    <p></p>
    <div id="ex_data">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" value="" /> I need a product demonstration, installation assistance and for other queries at no additional cost</div>

    <p></p>
    <div id="after_check">
    <div><textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="requirements" id="requirements" placeholder="Please provide your requirement here"></textarea></div>

    <h3>Address</h3>
    <div><textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Please provide your address for visit purpose"></textarea></div>
    </div>
    <span id="key_val">
    <h3>Please enter existing serial for extend subscription: </h3> 
    <div><input type="text" name="key" id="key" value="" /></div>
    </span>


    <h3>No. of licenses<span class="star_require">*</span> : </h3>
    <div><input type="text" name="licenses" id="licenses" value="" required /></div>

    <h3>Sub Total : </h3>
    <span id="sub_total"></span>
    <div><input type="hidden" name="price" id="hidden_subtotal" value="" /></div>

    <div><input class="form_btn" type="submit" id="continue_first" value="continue" /></div>
     </div>

    <div id="contact_details">
    h1 class="heading">Contact Details</h1>
    <h3>Email Address<span class="star_require">*</span>:</h3>
    <div><input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" required /></div>

    <h3>Mobile <span class="star_require">*</span>: </h3>
    <div><input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" value="" maxlength="10" required /></div>


    <div><input class="form_btn" type="submit" id="continue" value="continue" /></div>
    </div>

    <div id="billing_details">
    h1 class="heading">Billing Details</h1>
    <h3>Your Name/Organisation Name<span class="star_require">*</span>:</h3>
    <div><input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" required /></div>

    <h3>Your Area PIN code <span class="star_require">*</span>: </h3>
    <div><input type="text" id="pincode" name="pincode" value="" maxlength="10" required /></div>


    <div><input class="form_btn" type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" /></div>

    </div>
 </form>        


        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer();


/*contact form.js*/

// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#key_val").hide();
        $("div#ex_data").hide();
        $("div#after_check").hide();
        $no = $("#licenses").val();

        $("#licenses").keypress(function (e) {
             //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
             if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {              
                       return false;
            }
           });


        $("#course_master").change(function(){
            var cid = $(this).val();            
            if(cid == 2)
            {
                $("#key_val").show();
                $('#licenses').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $("div#ex_data").css("display","none");
            }
            else{
                $("#key_val").hide();
                $("div#ex_data").show(1000);
                $("#licenses").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"get_course_details.php",
                data:"cid="+cid,
                success:function(msg)
                {                   
                    $("#course_details").html(msg); 
                }
            });

        });

        $("#course_details").change(function(){
            var id = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"get_course_info.php",
                data:"id="+id,
                success:function(msg)
                {                   
                    $("#hidden_subtotal").val(msg); 
                    if($no == '')
                    {
                        var total = msg * 1;
                        $("#sub_total").text(total);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var total = msg * $no;
                        $("#sub_total").text(total);
                    }
                }
            });             
        });

        $("#check").click(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                $("div#after_check").show(1000);
                $("div#after_check #address").attr("required","true");
                $("div#after_check h3").append("<span class='star_require'>*</span>");
            }
            else
            {
                $("div#after_check").hide(1000);
                $("div#after_check #address").attr("required","false");
            }
        });



        $("#key").blur(function(){          
            var key = $("#key").val();
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"validate_key.php",
                data:"key="+key,
                success:function(msg)
                {                   
                    if(msg ==1)
                    {
                        $("#licenses").removeAttr("disabled");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#licenses').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    }
                }
            }); 

        });

        $("#licenses").blur(function(){         
            var subtotal = $("#hidden_subtotal").val();
            if(!isNaN(subtotal) && subtotal != '' && subtotal != 0)
            {
                subtotal = subtotal * $("#licenses").val();
                $("#sub_total").text(subtotal);
            }

        });

        $("#continue_first").click(function(){
            $("div#contact_details").css("display","block");

        });
        $("#continue").click(function(){
            $("div#billing_details").css("display","block");

        });

        $("#submit").click(function(){
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var mobile = $("#mobile").val();
            var pincode = $("#pincode").val();
            if( !isValidEmailAddress( email ) ) { 
                alert("invalid email address!"); return false;
            }
            else if(isNaN(mobile) || (mobile.length < 10) ) 
            {
                alert("invalid mobile no!"); return false;
            }
            else if(isNaN(pincode))
            {
                alert("Invalid Pincode!");return false;
            }
            else{
                alert("success");
                $( "#course_information" ).submit();
                return true;
            }

        });

    }); 



    //if( !isValidEmailAddress( emailaddress ) ) { /* do stuff here */ }

    function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = /^([a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+(\.[a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+)*|"((([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7e\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))*(([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?")@(([a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.)+([a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.?$/i;
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly for integrating from in wordpress you don't need to create config file and include. Just create template in theme which you are using and create page in wordpress admin and call this template.